# Change value on ng change

Tags: angularjs

I have to send the parameter through the input form to the API link.

This is my selecct

```
<select ng-model="selectedDay" ng-change="changedValue(selectedDay)" style="width: 117px;">
    <option ng-repeat="x in filterDays" value="{{x.showDays}}">{{x.showDays}}</option>
 </select>
```

And this is my controller

```
$scope.filterDays = [
    { showDays: "Last month", value: 30 },
    { showDays: "Last 14 days", value: 14 },
    { showDays: "Last 7 days", value: 7 }
];

$scope.show = $scope.filterDays[0].value;

$scope.changedValue = function (selectedDay) {
    $scope.show = selectedDay;
}

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/overviewStatisticTeam?days=" + $scope.show)
```

I have problem with sending paramter to API, when I change value on my select. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind value to your value attribute instead of showDays. Change the code like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.filterDays = [
    { showDays: "Last month", value: 30 },
    { showDays: "Last 14 days", value: 14 },
    { showDays: "Last 7 days", value: 7 }
];

$scope.show = $scope.filterDays[0].value;

$scope.changedValue = function (selectedDay) {
console.log(selectedDay)
    $scope.show = selectedDay;
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedDay" ng-change="changedValue(selectedDay)" style="width: 117px;">
    <option ng-repeat="x in filterDays" value="{{x.value}}">{{x.showDays}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```